# Is there a direct mapping of Flex' Vector to any Java type in Blazeds?

Tags: java, actionscript-3, apache-flex, vector, blazeds

In our Flex application we have an ActionScript3 class containing a property like this:

```
public var listOfThings:Vector.<Thing>;
```

And, in the corresponding Java class:

```
public Vector<Thing> listOfThings;
```

But we don't seem to be able to map that directly using BlazeDS (AMF3). We get this run-time error (sorry it's in Spanish):

```
TypeError: Error #1034: Error de conversión forzada: no se puede convertir
mx.collections::ArrayCollection@aa87ac1 en __AS3__.vec.Vector.<my.domain::Thing>.
```

Is there definitely no way to map Vector types between Java and AS3? I can't find a single example (but I do find a couple of low-level AMF3 attempts at [de]marshalling) therefore I take there isn't a way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such mapping.
You have 2 options which will preserve the marshalling of the vector content:

1. Convert your vector to an array
2. Convert your vector to a flex collection

Comment: Thanks. This confirms my suspicion. I'll just wait a few days before marking your answer as “accepted”, in case there's someone out there with a magical way to pass `Vector`s as `Vector`s.

Comment: No problem, but such solution doesn't exist!